# Sendmail authentication failed [# in password]

Tags: authentication, sendmail, sasl, smtp-auth

When sendmail is configured with password that starts with the character `#`, authentication is failed. Sendmail throwed an error that "AUTH=client, available mechanisms do not fulfill requirements".

Is this is a known issue.?
Is that a restriction with sendmail or ssl authentication or rules parsing?

Sample *default-auth-info* file :-

```
sendmailtest@gmail.com
sendmailtest@gmail.com
#12345678
smtp.gmail.com:587
LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 NTLM
```

LINUX platform

Sendmail version : 8.14.0

sasl version    : 2.1.22

Thanks in advance for the help..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `readauth` function in `sendmail/usersmtp.c` file ignores lines **starting** 
with `#`.

BTW Have you considered using `FEATURE(authinfo)` instead of `confDEF_AUTH_INFO`/`DefaultAuthInfo`?
Anyway `makemap` command also by default treats `#` as a comment indicator but it may be changed using `-D` command line option.